# PrivateLink for aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, vpc-endpoint

I need to create a private endpoint to access aurora service
so that public access to service is denied. As I am new to it .. so need help with this. I went through different docs but still not able to get the info I need.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What are you communicating with, the Aurora endpoint (performing SQL level interaction) or the service APIs themselves?

Comment: Hi @ChrisWilliams Its with aurora endpoint

Answer (score 0):

An Aurora database engine (as with every type of database engine in RDS) supports both external and internal variations of databases.

If your database endpoint is public this would have either been selected initial creation, or modified after it had been created.

[VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) in your context, would be used to connect to the RDS service (interacting with the API via SDK or CLI). Whereas you want to be able to just keep the traffic to your database private.

You can create a VPCLink to a Network Load Balancer to allow limited connectivity to resources, but this would be used to share outside of your VPC.

In Terraform this option is [publicly_accessible](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#publicly_accessible), which will define whether it is accessible outside the VPC (or its network connections) or not.